# Multi-threading with tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I am trying to build a software for fun, where a user can create buttons (prompt and key combination), and I want to create a separate thread that will listen to keyboard input to execute commands based on those prompts and make http requests when the keyboard is hit. Basically like a macro.
But I am struggling with multi threading and tkinter..
Here is the code :

Here is the button :

```
        self.run_btn_img = tk.PhotoImage(
            file=relative_to_assets("delete.png"))
        self.run_btn = tk.Button(
            image=self.run_btn_img,
            borderwidth=0,
            highlightthickness=0,
            command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=self.master.listener.start).start(),
            relief="flat"
        )
        self.run_btn.place(
            x=606.0,
            y=273.0,
            width=195.0,
            height=42.0
        )
```

Here is the listener class :

```
def print_running_threads():
    threads = threading.enumerate()
    for thread in threads:
        print(thread.name)

class Listener(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, key, buttons):
        super().__init__()
        self.query = AIQuery(key)
        self.buttons = buttons
        self.listener = None  # Initialize without starting
        self.thread = None

    def on_press(self, key):
        try:
            for button in self.buttons:
                if key.char == button.key:
                    self.query.makeQuery(button.prompt)
                    break
        except AttributeError:
            pass

    def start(self):
        # If there's already a listener, stop it first
        if self.listener:
            self.stop()
        self.listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=self.on_press)
        self.listener.start()
        self.listener.join()

    def stop(self):
        if self.listener:
            self.listener.stop()
            self.listener = None

    def update_buttons(self, new_buttons):
        self.buttons = new_buttons
```

As soon as I press the start button, it starts executing the start function and then the gui crashes and it throws me this error :
Process finished with exit code 133 (interrupted by signal 5: SIGTRAP)

PLEASE HELP !

Note: The self.master refers to the parent class which is a stack since I am using multiple tkinter frames with canvas. So it stores the listener there.

Comment: `self.listener.join()` in `Listener.start()` causes the main thread to block until the keyboard listener thread finishes. Get rid of it. [`keyboard.Listener` starts its own thread in the background](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#monitoring-the-keyboard),  you don't need to create another using `threading` module. The button's command would just be `self.master.listener.start`

Comment: @elmiomar I tried doing what you did but it still crashes, although now the start function gets executed. It crashes right after it finishes executing. Can you come on discord please ? I'd really really appreciate it..